# Generically search 3 separate dictionaries for value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've got an online game I'm working on and I'm trying to work out in this exact way how I would be able to get a single result from 3 different dictionaries using a generic search function.

This is for a player's sight but will not be used in a loop.

```
    protected Dictionary<UInt32, Character> _currentVisibleCharacters;
    protected Dictionary<UInt32, Item> _currentVisibleMapItems;
    protected Dictionary<UInt32, Npc> _currentVisibleNpcs;

    public Boolean GetVisibleObject<TObject>(UInt32 objId, out TObject obj) 
        where TObject : WorldObject
    {
          //I need to be able to search all 3 dictionaries with this function.
    }
```

It should use "objId" to search for an existing key/value pair in either of the 3 dictionaries. Once found, it should assign the value found to the parameter "obj". I've tried with LINQ, but I'm running into casting problems assigning, for example, an Npc value from the field _currentlyVisisbleNpcs to the "obj" parameter.

Character, Item, and Npc inherit from WorldObject.

Comment: You should be able to use Intersect with the default comparer for e.g. primaryDict.Keys.Intersect(secondaryDict.Keys)
                              .ToDictionary(t => t, t => primaryDict[t]); The result can be converted a well.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to check type so you don't get something from the wrong dictionary.

```
    public Boolean GetVisibleObject<T>(UInt32 objId, out T obj) 
        where T : WorldObject
    {
          //I need to be able to search all 3 dictionaries with this function.
          //It should use "objId" to search for an existing key in either of the 3.

        obj = null;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Character))
        {
            if (_currentVisibleCharacters.ContainsKey(objId))
            {
                obj = _currentVisibleCharacters[objId] as T;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Item))
        {
            if (_currentVisibleMapItems.ContainsKey(objId))
            {
                obj = _currentVisibleMapItems[objId] as T;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Npc))
        {
            if (_currentVisibleNpcs.ContainsKey(objId))
            {
                obj = _currentVisibleNpcs[objId] as T;
                return true;
            }
        }           

        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public TObject GetVisibleObject<TObject>(UInt32 objId) 
    where TObject : WorldObject, new()
{
     WorldObject match = null;

     match = _currentVisibleCharacters[objId];

     if (match == null)
        match = _currentVisibleMapItems[objId];

    if (match == null)
        match = _currentVisibleNpcs[objId];


    return (TObject)match;
}
```

Since all values stored in dictionaries inherit from WorldObject, you can return each potential match to WorldObject then cast to the more specific TObject type.

In addition, rather than using an out, return the type directly, which is more readable and usablel unless you absolutely need the boolean success value, which should be inferred instead from whether or not TObject is null.

The following test code returns a match of type Character.

```
_currentVisibleCharacters = new Dictionary<UInt32, Character>();
_currentVisibleCharacters.Add(0, new Character());
var match = GetVisibleObject<Character>(0);
Console.WriteLine(match);
Console.WriteLine(match.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have tried to make it simple by introducing my own class.

You can take this approach as a direction because I don't know exactly how your class structure is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Character
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Micky : Character
    {

    }

    class Minnie : Character
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mickeys = new Dictionary<Guid, Character>();
            var searchKey = Guid.NewGuid  ();
            mickeys.Add(searchKey, new Micky { Name = "Micky A"});
            mickeys.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), new Micky { Name = "Micky B" });

            var minnies = new Dictionary<Guid, Character>();
            minnies.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), new Minnie { Name = "Minnie A" });
            minnies.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), new Minnie { Name = "Minnie B" });


            var searchedItem = mickeys.Union(minnies).Where(k => k.Key == searchKey).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(searchedItem.Value.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

Points to consider:

1. You don't need to create 3 dictionary as you can create one Dictionary (as long as keys are unique ). You can create one dictionary of parent class and set value of N number of children. This point will cover L of SOLID principles (LSP (Liskov substitution principle))
2. If you want to have a separate dictionary then use Union to combine these and then search by key.